# Android AbstractAccountAuthenticator authTokenType is always null

Tags: android, accountmanager

I want to create an Android custom account.

I have implemented a class which extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator:

```
public class Authenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    private static final String TAG = "Authenticator";
    protected Context mContext;

    public Authenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Authenticator");
        this.mContext = context;
    }       

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Log.i(TAG, "addAccount");

    // ...
    }

// ...
}
```

When i want to add an account from the android settings account page, the addAccount() is called but the String **authTokenType** is always null.
This is annoying because I need it for the AccountManager function setAuthToken().

Why is this parameter null?

**EDIT:**

If I add an account from my application via AccountManager, I can specify the string authTokenType:

```
mAccountManager.addAccount(
                getString(R.string.authenticator_account_type),
                getString("Full access"), // authTokenType parameter
                null,
                new Bundle(),
                this,
                new OnAccountAddComplete(),
                null);
```

How can I specify it in the settings page add account process?